# How to drop a formula in the other columns?

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofill

I have a table, with a formula in a cell, in the example it's C8.

I need to autofill the formula horizontally, from the cell to an indefinite column. The idea is to autofill horizontally the formula for all the headers. The number of headers can increase due to precedent steps.

I cannot make fix the drag and drop formula since the number of rows will increase.

I need a formula like

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

but for a horizontal and self adapting autofill.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the analogous horizontal fill, try this

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! It doesn't work, for now... Does this help you to know that my headers are in row 3?

Comment: ok. so headers are in row 3, what cell has the formula that you want to copy to the right?

Comment: The cell that has the formula to be copied to the right is the cell C8, in this case, but I as I said in the future, the number of lines in the file will increase

Thanks !

Comment: I was working on the other answer while you were writing this comment.  Post a picture like the one I included in my other answer so I can see the structure of the data.  With that image, the code will be easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your data is set up similar to the image below and you want to fill the formula in B4 to fill below the headers in row 3.

[image]

If so, this code will do the trick.  I should work regradless of where the table is, as long as it has the same structure.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection.Offset(-1), Cells(Selection.Offset(-1).Row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Offset(1)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```